# File Path to jar inside another jar

Tags: file, jar, eclipse-plugin

For an Eclipse plugin, I need to refer to a jar file inside the plugin directory (to provide code to users). This works perfectly when running the plugin while developing (inside a runtime-eclipse-application).

But when I build an update site, my plugin is built into a jar file. File paths for images are still working, but when the jar should be imported, eclipse shows the following error:
`Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'DoodleDebug' references non existing library 'file:\C:\Users\Me\.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_740800064\plugins\ch.unibe.scg.doodledebug_1.0.0.201208281642.jar!\DoodleDebug-Client.jar'`

The outer jar path is correct and when inspecting it with WinRAR, I can see the desired jar file inside it!

Why isn't this working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install your plugin in an exploded form.  To do this, in your MANIFEST.MF file, add the following line:

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

This will ensure that your plugin is installed as a directory, not a jar file.  There is no way to reference nested jars, so they must be exploded.

See here for more information: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/01/20/tip-eclipse-bundleshape/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also had to check `Unpack the plug-in archive after the installation` in the plugin's manifest file (under the tab `Plug-ins`).